# Manifest sync error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I wanted to go back and continue my android app after 4 month, what happend is that manifest doesn't sync with the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

and my manifest is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arnick.bazim"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "0.9.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : #the one signal app id,

                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'

    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

if that matters, I'm using local gralde version 4.2.1
I have also checked gradle 4.3.1 and non-local gradle but the error is still there.
Is there anything I am missing?
I remember about 5 6 months ago I faced the same issue I guess, and that was related to onesignal version but I do not remember what happened I just know I changed the version and error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

use same version as at top of gradle file **26.0.2**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arnick.bazim"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "0.9.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : #the one signal app id,

                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "versionName", variant.versionName
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'

    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

clean and rebuild this may help...

Answer (score 0):

Use the **same version of support libraries**:

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```